Finding the correct power input for a battery pack powered device
I want to find the correct input voltage and current a device needs so that I can replace its battery pack with wired DC power. I suspect it's what it says on the device itself and not on the battery pack, but I need confirmation as I do not fully understand why the values differ.
The battery pack label says:
3.6V 6700mAh 24.12Wh
Charging Voltage: 4.2V
Rechargeable Lithium-ion Battery

The device's battery compartment label says:
Battery Input Rating: 5V ⎓ 1A

Is the correct input then 5VDC, 1A?



Perhaps some photos would provide added information to help interpret.

The battery is nominal 3.6V but charges at 4.2V; that tells you that
the device will work on a 4V source, with a few tenths of volt tolerance.
It isn't clear what peak current requirement is, because 1.0A can
be applied for hours to cover a few minutes of battery discharge
at 2A.   Presumably the difference between '5V' input and 4.2V battery
charge is not important if you're replacing the battery with your other power source.
When operating without the original battery, the 5V that makes the battery-charge circuitry work, is an irrelevance (because, no battery to charge).   It's the OTHER circuitry, that the battery suffices for, that  matters.

It's looking like 4V +/- 0.1V may be it. Using a multimeter while it's operation, I measured about 4.05V with spikes up to 4.16V and dips down to 3.95V. Does this mean a 4V DC adapter should do fine, so as long as the max current is high enough?

@E-71 Yes, a "4V DC" adapter should work.   Probably the permissible variation is larger than you detect in operation, though: it has a good likelihood to continue operation down to the battery's nominal 3.6V.
